# how to populate map in header file in C++

Tags: c++

how do I populate map in header file? I have `map<int,int>sample` which needs to be populated in header file. Right now I am populating it in .cpp file in local function I want to move this code in header file.

Comment: "which needs to be populated in header file" – sounds like a design error.

Comment: You provide a inline constructor definition and initialize your map class member in your header file?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you provide the code

Comment: @debonair For what?? Can you provide what you already have now first please?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I don't see the use case where it is required to populate something in a header file (excluding templates) because of a _"design error"_ - can you give an example for this?

Comment: @tomse:  Variable declarations (creating instances of) should not be in header files.  This means that every source file that includes the variable, whether it uses it or not.  This is also part of the "No Global Variables" policy or search for "C++ Global Variables Are Evil".

Answer (score 2):

> how do I populate map in header file?

You can do it just like initializing any other variable.

> I have `map<int,int>sample` which needs to be populated in header file.

That does not sound like a good requirement. Perhaps there is a flaw in your design. Try to provide access to global data through a function. You can easily convert that to:

```
map<int,int>& getSample();
```

in a header file. You can implement that in a .cpp file any way you wish to. E.g.

```
map<int,int>& getSample()
{     
   static map<int,int> sample = constructSample(); // Assuming you can create such a function.
   return sample;
}
```

> That Right now I am populating it in .cpp file in local function I want to move this code in header file.

That does not sound like a good idea. Don't do it if you can avoid it.